# Downloaded html page doesn't recognize utf-8 characters

Tags: html, r, utf-8, download

I use R to download html page:

```
download.file("https://sljeme.usud.hr/usud/praksaw.nsf/Praksa/C12570D30061CE54C1257BEC0043CA4C?OpenDocument",
              destfile = paste0("test", ".html"),
              mode = "wb")
```

The file is downloaded successfully but when I open it in windows it doesn't show some Croatian characters (č, ć). I have also tried to save html file with `write.table`, but that doesn't help.

I don't see any metadata on `charset` in html source code. Is that the main problem and how to overcome this issue?

Comment: "*I don't see any metadata on `charset` in html source code*" - did you check if the HTTP response headers have a charset specified? That would take priority if present.

Comment: @Remy Labeau, your tip help me. Headers had `windows-1250` encoding specified, so I set encoding to `windows-1250` , and then saved with write.table and `file.encoding = "UTF-8"`.